# ImageView function

Tags: android, layout, imageview

So, I'm totally new to Android programming. I want my ImageView to change its image depending on the result of the coded function.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/server"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

So, what should I write to make the ImageView do something (I mean the "status" ImageView, it's the last one) just by itself? No clicking or pressing.

Comment: Just call `imageView.setImageBitmap()` or `imageView.setImageResource()`

Comment: What do you want to do?It's not clear at all.

Comment: "No clicking or pressing" means you want an image set from the start on the ImageView (using android:src="@drawable/image" directly in XML) OR you want the line of code imageView.setImageBitmap(...) / imageView.setImageResource(...) OR do you want it to happen automatically after a set amount of time OR do you want it to change when something happens anywhere else in your app?

Comment: Src? Maybe you use Google at first?

Comment: Well, I might be unprecise. I want my image in ImageView to change depending on the function result. 

Let's say there are 2 images: image1 and image2. If the result of the function is true, image1 is displayed. Else image2 is. That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

1)Right-click on drawable folder and choose add existing file, then choose a image from your computer.

2)Then add this line under your imageview in your xaml file:  android:background="@drawable/NameOfThePictureThatYouJustAddedToTheDrawableFolder"

`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/server"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/NameOfThePictureThatYouJustAddedToTheDrawableFolder"
        />`